# Need to run three select queries without using union

Tags: sql

I am using three select queries to show three data from the same view but using different timelines for showing the data.
The only difference in all the three select queries is just timelines or the dates.
So can anyone tell me how to combine results of three select query having three different timelines at the same time into a single select query without using union.

```
select count(*) count from data where status in ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') 
and status_date >= '01-NOV-18' and status_date <= '31-JAN-19' 
UNION 
select count(*) count from data where status in ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') 
and status_date >= '01-FEB-19' and status_date <= '30-APR-19'
UNION 
select count(*) count from data where status in ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') 
and status_date >= '01-MAY-19' and status_date <= '31-JUL-19' order by count desc;
```

Expected result :
Count
100 (1st timeline)
200 (2nd timeline)
300 (3rd timeline)

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: if the query is timing out, then maybe look at why that is? what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: it uses normal sql queries

Comment: leave the timeout part because it is related to my frontend so just focus on how to write this three select query into one select query.

Comment: UNION ALL would be better here. Consider the case two counts are the same.

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. And any explain/execution plan output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2019-01-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30' THEN 1 END) AS cnt2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt3
FROM data
WHERE
    status IN ('ACCEPTED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED');
```

If your database supports CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2019-01-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30' THEN 1 END) AS cnt2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt3
    FROM data
    WHERE status IN ('ACCEPTED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED')
)

SELECT cnt1 FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cnt2 FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cnt3 FROM cte;
```

Comment: It seems OP needs 3 rows with a single column. Your solution returns a single row with 3 columns. But this may not be a problem.

Comment: I need only single column with the column name as count

Comment: presenting the data count of three different result in a single column

Comment: @jarlh Yeah...I though of that, but thing is, that might perform worse than what the OP already has, and also it assumes his database supports CTE.

Comment: Your query is probably 2 to almost 3 times faster than the original query. To unpivot 1 row into 3 rows takes no time at all.

Comment: you are using case which act as if else , but i want the result of all three select queries.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer, it helped me a lot.